# PHP code working on one server, not on another

Tags: php

My *development* server runs my PHP web application smoothly on PHP 5.3.8.

However, when upgrading my PHP *production* server from PHP 5.2.6 to 5.3.8 I got several problems with this application (complaints about deprecated function `ereg_replace` and missing `date.timezone` settings) which forced me to order a rollback to 5.2.6.

How can the same PHP code work fine on one 5.3.8 server and not on another? What are common causes for this behavior? Any suggestions?

Comment: probably level of error handling is different on your dev vs prod server - i.e. same issues, just some not visible on dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please access php.ini (PHP configuration file) on both server.
Find the line "; display_errors"

Please compare the following lines after that.

These are the options available for the three settings variable:

```
; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: NOTE: from what we read in the OP the configuration is the wrong way round. Development server should have intense error reporting whilst the production server should be silent.

Comment: Thanks. I have `display_errors = On` on the production server. Obviously that seems like a misconfiguration. But I'm not sure whether these messages to `STDOUT` would actually crash the application, as I am experiencing. Wouldn't they just appear as console messages?

Comment: You can log the errors on the log file. The setting for logging error is just below the error reporting line in "php.ini". Following the optional value for the setting.

`; log_errors

;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On
`

Comment: @IvenMS Good idea. The documentation says "You're strongly advised to use error logging in place of error displaying on production web sites."

Answer (score 3):

Your error level settings are not the same on your machines.

FYI:

- ereg_replace is deprecated and using it is highly discouraged
- every call to a date/time function will generate a E_NOTICE if the
  timezone isn't valid, and/or a E_WARNING message if using the system
  settings or the TZ environment variable

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility. Unfortunately I had to think too fast when things crashed so I did not have time to investigate what `php.ini` settings looked like before rollback. However, _before_ upgrading the setting was `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` and I don't expect such settings to be modified by upgrades. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is an evolving language, same for Java or c#, so it means you have to check the documentation if some functions are not deprecated and update your code accordingly.

Also you have to make sure your PHP settings are the same on both servers.

If you check the [`ereg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) documentation there is this blurb:

> Warning This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on
>   this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: Yes, the configuration file `php.ini` is a prime suspect. I will put more time into investigating this. To avoid more production server rollbacks I will deploy the application on a _new_ server, retiring the old when the upgrade works.

Answer (score 1):

are you totally positive that your development server runs PHP 5.3.8?
All `ereg_*` functions are deprecated in PHP 5.3.X, so your code should not run on PHP 5.3 without any warning. if so, that is weird because your development server should generate more warnings (e.g. `E_ALL`) than your production server. Check your error reporting settings in `php.ini`. (`display_errors`, `error_reporting`)

to make it fly, you should really search for any occurance of `ereg_*` and replace these expressions with a `preg_*` equivalent.

date.timezone can be set in your `php.ini`. After that, i see less reason why your PHP 5.2.6 code should not run on 5.3.6.

Comment: the ereg_ function are still available simply PHP would emit a warning, they are doing because in a near future the function would be removed for real.

Comment: @RageZ that is the correct definition of "deprecated". nevertheless it is the right course of action to actually react on the deprecation by replacing the function calls with preg instead of just suppressing the error message.

Comment: Thanks. From what I've seen `ereg_replace` is still available in PHP 5.3.8, but highly discouraged. I will remove it in due course.

Comment: @Kaii Forgot to state that phpinfo outputs PHP Version 5.3.8-1~dotdeb.1.